# The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found `None`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to make some LSTM+CNN hybrid for my college project and here's my code

```
def model_robo():
  grid=tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,10,12),dtype=tf.float32)
  print(grid.shape)
  cnn_result=tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D(1,kernel_size=(3,3),data_format="channels_first"))(grid)
  cnn_result=tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(2,2))(cnn_result)
  cnn_result=tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(flatten())(cnn_result)
  lstm_input=Concatenate()([price,cnn_result])
  masked_position=Masking(mask_value=-1)(lstm_input)
  result=LSTM(50, name='LSTM')(masked_position)
  prediction=(TimeDistributed(Dense(1,activation="relu")))(result)
  model=tf.keras.Model(inputs=[grid,price],outputs=[prediction])
  optim=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001,amsgrad=False)
  model.compile(optimizer=optim,loss='mae')
  return model
```

but when I'm trying to call the model with

```
model=model_robo()
```

it gives:

```
ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found None
```

which stems from:

```
cnn_result=tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D(1,kernel_size=(3,3),data_format="channels_first"))(grid)
```

I've tried searching for answer but I think most error comes from the images format like [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5900) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013918/valueerror-the-channel-dimension-of-the-inputs-should-be-defined-found-none) while I don't really use one (the CNN input is numerical matrix put together to form an "image"). the would-be input is 2159x1x10x12 matrix and the `grid.shape` result is (none,1,10,12)

how can i fix this?
let me know if you need additional information and thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure it is a bug or something else, but to get rid of `channels_first`, you may use reshape layer like `grid = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((10,12,1))(grid)`. Then you can remove `channels_first` argument.

Comment: It gives `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 12, 1)` now but it probably works.
It delete the second dimension for some reason. I'll make a new thread once I properly read the existing solutions. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after I delete the `channels_first` (and changed it to `Conv1D` but that's another matters. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992377/conv2d-lost-a-dimension-from-tensor-resulting-in-incompatible-dimension-error) for detail)

My hypothesis is `channels_first` took the first dimension (None) as the channel instead of the second one. [API docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) said first channel should be reserved for batch size but like the comment said, it's probably a bug